# Rails Route Globbing with URL as parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a route that looks like this:
`match '/:id/*url', to: 'main#parse', :constraints => {:url => /.*/}, as: 'parser',   via: 'get'`

when i type in a URL that looks like this:
`http://www.domain.com/foo/http://www.bar.com`

then the url param always seems to strip one of the forward slashes, leaving me with http:/www.bar.com

How can i get it to keep the double slash?

Thanks!

Comment: you will have to escape the url for this to work. you are not allowed to have `http://` as a part of the url!

Comment: Really? I don't see why not though - i figured that with globbing, it would/should just treat it as a string. Do you know the technical reason why you are not allowed to have "http://" as part of the URL? Again, it seems to work, but it just strips the second forward slash. Even if I pass something like http://www.bar.com//again it will remove one of the forward slashes from before the "again"

Comment: yes, that is true. what i meant is that this part won't be treated the way you probably want it to be. you would usually use `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bar.com` so that the browser does not try to use the colons and slashes as path separators.